# How can I add multiple buttons to the header bar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, button, header

(Disclaimer: I'm new to jQuery mobile.)

I have a header bar with a back button, some header text, and then a home button.

Code:

```
<div class="headerDiv" data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <a id="backButton" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="a">Back</a>
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <a href="index.cfm" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="a">Home</a>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I'm trying to add an additional "logout" button to the right of the header text, and the left of the home button. I'd like it to appear just like the other 2 buttons. When I try adding it in it causes the home button to wrap to the next line.

Code:

```
<div class="headerDiv" data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <a id="backButton" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="a">Back</a>
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <a href="logout.cfm" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Logout</a>
    <a href="index.cfm" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="a">Home</a>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I did a bit of research (aka googling, as well as poking around other SO posts) and came up with the following code, which adds a sort of sub-button-bar to the right of the header text:

```
<div class="headerDiv" data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <a id="backButton" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="a">Back</a>
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <div class="ui-btn-right" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="logout.cfm" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Logout</a>
        <a href="index.cfm" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="a">Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

This is the closest I've managed to get, but I'd really like to have the logout and home buttons as separate discrete buttons. I like the look of the default header bar and would prefer to adapt it somehow rather than customizing my own navbar. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: you can use jQM _grids_, but this will involve some @media to adjust `.ui-grid-solo`'s width on smaller screens http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Ab2QA/

Comment: @Omar, how about data-inline="true" within the containing div: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Ab2QA/2/ ? I think this would work if no wrapping is desired...

Comment: @ezanker, an upvote is awaiting you ;)